# Socket.io and jQuery - combine

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I have the following code:

connectionCounter.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var socket = require("socket.io");
var server = app.listen(4000);
var io = socket.listen(server);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
 response.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

var activeClients = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){clientConnect(socket)});

function clientConnect(socket){
 activeClients +=1;
 io.sockets.emit('message', {clients:activeClients});
 socket.on('disconnect', function(){clientDisconnect()}); 
}

function clientDisconnect(){
  activeClients -=1;
  io.sockets.emit('message', {clients:activeClients});
}
```

index.html (count connected clients to website)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Connection Counter</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      function msgReceived(msg){
        $clientCounter.html(msg.clients);
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $clientCounter = $("#client_count")

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
        socket.on('message', function(msg){msgReceived(msg)});
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><span id="client_count">0</span> connected clients</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and index.html (jQuery Knob)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Knob demo</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function($) {

                $(".knob").knob({
                    change : function (value) {
                        //console.log("change : " + value);
                    },
                    release : function (value) {
                        //console.log(this.$.attr('value'));
                        console.log("release : " + value);
                    },
                    cancel : function () {
                        console.log("cancel : ", this);
                    },
                    draw : function () {

                        // "tron" case
                        if(this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

                            var a = this.angle(this.cv)  // Angle
                                , sa = this.startAngle          // Previous start angle
                                , sat = this.startAngle         // Start angle
                                , ea                            // Previous end angle
                                , eat = sat + a                 // End angle
                                , r = 1;

                            this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

                            this.o.cursor
                                && (sat = eat - 0.3)
                                && (eat = eat + 0.3);

                            if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                                ea = this.startAngle + this.angle(this.v);
                                this.o.cursor
                                    && (sa = ea - 0.3)
                                    && (ea = ea + 0.3);
                                this.g.beginPath();
                                this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                                this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sa, ea, false);
                                this.g.stroke();
                            }

                            this.g.beginPath();
                            this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor ;
                            this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sat, eat, false);
                            this.g.stroke();

                            this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                            this.g.beginPath();
                            this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                            this.g.arc( this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                            this.g.stroke();

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Example of infinite knob, iPod click wheel
                var v, up=0,down=0,i=0
                    ,$idir = $("div.idir")
                    ,$ival = $("div.ival")
                    ,incr = function() { i++; $idir.show().html("+").fadeOut(); $ival.html(i); }
                    ,decr = function() { i--; $idir.show().html("-").fadeOut(); $ival.html(i); };
                $("input.infinite").knob(
                                    {
                                    min : 0
                                    , max : 20
                                    , stopper : false
                                    , change : function () {
                                                    if(v > this.cv){
                                                        if(up){
                                                            decr();
                                                            up=0;
                                                        }else{up=1;down=0;}
                                                    } else {
                                                        if(v < this.cv){
                                                            if(down){
                                                                incr();
                                                                down=0;
                                                            }else{down=1;up=0;}
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    v = this.cv;
                                                }
                                    });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            body{
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0px 50px;
              font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              font-weight: 300;
              text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
            }
            p{font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px}
            div.demo{text-align: center; width: 280px; float: left}
            div.demo > p{font-size: 20px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="big" class="demo" style="height:800px;width:100%">
            <p>&#215; Big !</p>
            <pre>
data-width="700"
            </pre>
            <input class="knob" data-min="0" data-max="100" data-width="700" data-height="700" data-thickness=".7" data-cursor=true>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to combine the two index.html, but with no luck. The work separately, but when i combine and try to run nodejs, the counter does not work and the knob does not show.

Any suggestions?

howto: http://www.scottblaine.com/getting-started-node-js-socket-io/

jQuery Knob: https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob

combined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Knob demo</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            function msgReceived(msg){
                $clientCounter.html(msg.clients);
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $clientCounter = $("#client_count")

                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
                socket.on('message', function(msg){msgReceived(msg)});
            });

            $(function($) {

                $(".knob").knob({
                    change : function (value) {
                        //console.log("change : " + value);
                    },
                    release : function (value) {
                        //console.log(this.$.attr('value'));
                        console.log("release : " + value);
                    },
                    cancel : function () {
                        console.log("cancel : ", this);
                    },
                    draw : function () {

                        // "tron" case
                        if(this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

                            var a = this.angle(this.cv)  // Angle
                                , sa = this.startAngle          // Previous start angle
                                , sat = this.startAngle         // Start angle
                                , ea                            // Previous end angle
                                , eat = sat + a                 // End angle
                                , r = 1;

                            this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

                            this.o.cursor
                                && (sat = eat - 0.3)
                                && (eat = eat + 0.3);

                            if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                                ea = this.startAngle + this.angle(this.v);
                                this.o.cursor
                                    && (sa = ea - 0.3)
                                    && (ea = ea + 0.3);
                                this.g.beginPath();
                                this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                                this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sa, ea, false);
                                this.g.stroke();
                            }

                            this.g.beginPath();
                            this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor ;
                            this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sat, eat, false);
                            this.g.stroke();

                            this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                            this.g.beginPath();
                            this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                            this.g.arc( this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                            this.g.stroke();

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Example of infinite knob, iPod click wheel
                var v, up=0,down=0,i=0
                    ,$idir = $("div.idir")
                    ,$ival = $("div.ival")
                    ,incr = function() { i++; $idir.show().html("+").fadeOut(); $ival.html(i); }
                    ,decr = function() { i--; $idir.show().html("-").fadeOut(); $ival.html(i); };
                $("input.infinite").knob(
                                    {
                                    min : 0
                                    , max : 20
                                    , stopper : false
                                    , change : function () {
                                                    if(v > this.cv){
                                                        if(up){
                                                            decr();
                                                            up=0;
                                                        }else{up=1;down=0;}
                                                    } else {
                                                        if(v < this.cv){
                                                            if(down){
                                                                incr();
                                                                down=0;
                                                            }else{down=1;up=0;}
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    v = this.cv;
                                                }
                                    });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            body{
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0px 50px;
              font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              font-weight: 300;
              text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
            }
            p{font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px}
            div.demo{text-align: center; width: 280px; float: left}
            div.demo > p{font-size: 20px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><span id="client_count">0</span> connected clients</p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="big" class="demo" style="height:800px;width:100%">
            <p>&#215; Big !</p>
            <pre>
data-width="700"
            </pre>
            <input class="knob" data-min="0" data-max="100" data-width="700" data-height="700" data-thickness=".7" data-cursor=true>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Different versions of jQuery may have a hand in it

Comment: @tymeJV Tried to alter, no effect.. btw new to javascript (and programming in general...(

Comment: Can you post how you're trying to combine them, something will probably jump out :)

Answer (score 0):

From what i see in your code.

`io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){clientConnect(socket)});`

The socket is specific to the client it connected. So the messages are sent to that particular client only. If you want to broadcast messages to all clients. You need to specifically send messages to all sockets

http://michaelheap.com/sending-messages-to-certain-clients-with-socket-io/

Comment: I do not think this is the problem, since the code is working fine separately. I use io.sockets.emit